# Can I assign a servlet to a particular domain?

Tags: java, servlets

I have two CNAME-s pointed to the same server. I want to assign one servlet to the first CNAME and another one to the second CNAME. Can I do it in `web.xml` (or somehow else without manual parsing of `ServletRequest`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the idea to have a [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), and in it have a condition based on [`ServletRequest#getServerName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29) and *dispatch* the request to appropriate servlet, will do.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
throws IOException, ServletException {
    ...
    [other processing/validations]
    ...
    if(request.getServerName().equals("domain1.com"))
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet1").forward(request, response)
    else
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2").forward(request, response)

}
```

obviously, you could have `<init-param>` in your `web.xml` to dynamically set the domains, so that you could change these values based on your build profile.